# What to use: Change Data Capture or Materialized View?

Tags: oracle11g, materialized-views, cdc

Objective: I want to replicate table from one oracle DB to another asynchronously.
Please advice, which one of the two, Change Data Capture or Materialized View , is better option with benefit realization for the choice.

Comment: You may want to avoid Change Data Capture since it will be de-supported soon: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/cdc.htm

Comment: As per Oracle support team, CDC will be supported with the existing functionality but there will be no enhancement and bug fixing. It won't be de-supported.